# Java - Running totals(using do while and if else statements)

Tags: java, if-statement, do-while

I'm not very adept in getting the running totals using Java as I've started recently. I have to display and hold the running total of the bank balance and for some strange reason, it's resetting back to 100, which is what I declared it as to start with. Is there any way for me to stop the bank balance from being reset every time it loops?

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice, totBal = 0, totWith = 0, totDep = 0;
    double with, remBal = 0, deposit, bankBal = 100;
    char reply = 0;

    do
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Bank online\n");
        System.out.println("1. Withdraw");
        System.out.println("2. Deposit");
        System.out.println("3. Balance");
        System.out.println("4. Account Details");
        System.out.println("5. Exit\n");
        System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
        choice = sc.nextInt();

        if(choice == 1)
        {
            System.out.print("How much do you wish to withdraw?\n");
            with = sc.nextInt();
            remBal = bankBal - with;
            System.out.println("Your new balance is: " + remBal);
            totWith++;
        }
        else if(choice == 2)
        {  
            System.out.print("How much do you wish to deposit?\n");
            deposit = sc.nextInt();
            remBal = remBal + deposit;
            System.out.println("Your new balance is: " + remBal);
            totDep++;
        }
        else if(choice == 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Your balance is: " + remBal);
            totBal++;
        }
        else if(choice == 4)
        {
            System.out.println("You made " + totWith + " withdrawls from your account.");
            System.out.println("You made " + totDep + " deposits to your account.");
            System.out.println("You made " + totBal + " balance checks on your account.");
        }
        else if(choice == 5)
        {

        }

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Do you want to enter another option?(y/n): ");
        reply = sc.next().charAt(0);

    }while(reply == 'Y' || reply == 'y');

    System.out.println("Thank you and goodbye!");
}
```

}

Also, I feel that I have WAY too many variables. How can I cut back on these?

Comment: Use object oriented approach.

Comment: Also your totBal is going to be set to 100 because you have not changed the value of it in anywhere in your if statements, you were only changing the value of remBal. I would recommend using methods called from a switch-case to lessen the variables.

Comment: try to implement get/set methods and use them in your loops

Comment: I feel like your usage of `bankBal` and `totBal` is completely ambiguous which is causing you confusion. `bankBal` is set to 100 and *never* changed, just referenced.

Comment: @tnw Yep fixed it now. Thanks. Solved

Comment: Your code could use a lot of cleaning up. The friendly people at [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) could probably give you a lot more advice if you wanted it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with following statement:

```
 double with, remBal = 0, deposit, bankBal = 100;
```

Here you are initialising remBal as 0, while when one deposits amount/checks balance you do:

```
 remBal = remBal + deposit;//you use remBal for blaance check
```

So on first attempt it will try to add 0 with say $100 which will be 100 while bankBal is 100 it should be 100. So initialize remBal same as bankBal (or use just one variable for bankBalance i.e. either of one).

Answer (score 0):

You set the bankBal value to 100 at the start of the program.
When doing withdrawals, you always do

```
remBal = bankBal - with
```

which will always equate to

```
remBal = 100 - with
```

since you never change bankBal to reflect the updated balance after each loop.
One approach to solve this is to remove the

```
bankBal
```

variable altogether and simply set your

```
remBal
```

variable to your desired starting value.
Finally change the withdrawal computation mentioned above to

```
remBal = remBal - with
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is implement switch-cases to call methods specific to Depost, Withdraw, etc. An example of this roughly would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please Enter what you would like to do: ");
    String enterPrompt = input.next();
    int options = 5;
    switch (options) {
        case 1:  enterPrompt = "Deposit";
                 doDeposit();
                 break;
        case 2:  enterPrompt = "Withdrawel";
                 doWithdrawel();
                 break;
        case 3:  enterPrompt = "Balance";
                 viewBalance();
                 break;
        case 4:  enterPrompt = "Account Details";
                 viewAccount();
                 break;
        case 5:  enterPrompt = "Exit";
                 System.exit(1);
                 break;
    }
     public void doDeposit(){
     //local variables here
     //Do stuff
      }
     public void doWithdrawel(){
     //local variables here
     //Do stuff
    }
     public void viewBalance(){
    //local variables here
    //Do stuff
    }
     public void viewAccount(){
    //local variables here
    //Do stuff
    }

}
```